# Creating image files that's named in numerical sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that's supposed to open a png image and then resize it and then save it as an jpg in numerical sequence. But the code for the number sequencing I copied from the internet isn't working with PIL. It gives me the exception "KeyError: 'W'"

```
import os
from PIL import Image

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\paul\\Downloads')

# open canvas.png
original = Image.open('canvas.png')

# resize image height to 2160
size = (3000, 2160)
original.thumbnail(size)

# convert to RGB
RGB = original.convert('RGB')

# save image as sequence
i = 0
while os.path.exists("image%s.jpg" % i):
    i += 1

RGB.save("image%s.jpg" % i, "w")
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question text.

Comment: "Copied from the internet." Maybe you want to limit that a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit based on Haken Lid's comment**

The PIL documentation says that the function save accepts these argument:

```
Image.save(fp, format=None, **params)
```

The parameter `w` you passed is not within the set of accepted file format. 
 [Here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html) you can see which formats are accepted. To make it works, just drop the `w` argument and substitute the `%s` with %d (i is an integer, not a string):

```
RGB.save("image%d.jpg" % i)
```

---

**Note**: from your tags it is not clear if you're using python2 or python3. If you are using python 3, I suggest to use the new method to format string:

```
RGB.save("image{}.jpg".format(i))
```

You can even specify a padding so that you can sort your file by name later on:

```
RGB.save("image{:04d}.jpg".format(i))
```

where 4 means that your number will be padded with zeros as to have length of at least 4.

Comment: You are not completely right. The docs you are quoting is for multi frame images, such as animated GIFS. For regular images, you can provide a format string as the second argument (for example 'jpg'). But `w` is not a supported image format, so your answer should fix the problem. [Image.save() docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)

Comment: Since python3.6 we can also use f-strings here: `f'image{i:04}.jpg'`

Comment: @HåkenLid you're right, I'll edit my answer, thanks!